# ISTIO External Auth : '503 upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection terminationroot' when access over HTTPS

Tags: istio

**ISTIO version:  1.9.4
EKS Cluster version: 1.14**

We have deployed ISTIO APP mesh in our project. We have deployed External Authorization using istio's documentation i.e. https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-custom/.

External authorizer used (as mentioned in above documentation) : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.9/samples/extauthz/ext-authz.yaml

When we access any API from going into pod of another API (i.e. over http), using curl command, all works fine. External auth service gets call and all the headers are passed into external authorizer's v3 check method. Below information is passed
source, principal, destination, headers: authority, method, path, accept, content-length, user-agent, x-b3-sampled, x-b3-spanid, x-b3-traceid, x-envoy-attempt-count, x-ext-authz, x-forwarded-client-certx-forwarded-proto, x-request-id.

But when we try to access the same service over https using postman, browser or from going into pod of another API and using curl with https endpoint, we get denied response from external authorizer's v3 check method. Also when we check the logs of external authorizer's v3 check method no headers are passed to it in this case.

Below is setup

**Name spaces with ISTIO ejection enable : foo**

**1. ISTIO Config map changes**

```
data:
  mesh: |-
    # Add the following content to define the external authorizers.
    extensionProviders:
    - name: "sample-ext-authz-grpc"
      envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
        service: "ext-authz.foo.svc.cluster.local"
        port: "9000"
    - name: "sample-ext-authz-http"
      envoyExtAuthzHttp:
        service: "ext-authz.foo.svc.cluster.local"
        port: "8000"
        includeHeadersInCheck: ["x-ext-authz"]
```

**2. External Authorizer**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ext-authz
  namespace: foo 
  labels:
    app: ext-authz
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  - name: grpc
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: ext-authz
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ext-authz
  namespace: foo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ext-authz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ext-authz
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/istio/ext-authz:0.6
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: ext-authz
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        - containerPort: 9000
```

**3. Enable the external authorization Config**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ext-authz
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-api
  action: CUSTOM
  provider:
    name: sample-ext-authz-grpc
  rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        paths: ["/user/api/*"]
```

**4. PeerAuth Chagnes**

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: mtlsauth
  namespace: foo
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

**5. Destination Rule**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: foo
spec:
  host: "*.samplehost.svc.cluster.local"
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

**6. Virtual Service File**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: sample-gateway
  namespace: foo
spec: 
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "sample.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: user-api
  namespace: foo
spec: 
  hosts:
  - "sample.com"
  gateways:
  - sample-gateway
  http:
  - match: 
    - uri:   
        prefix: /user/api/ 
    route:
    - destination:
        host: user-api
        port:
          number: 9500
```

Logs from ingress gateway:

> 2021-07-08T11:13:33.554104Z   warning envoy config    StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.20.0.51:15012: connect: connection refused"
> 2021-07-08T11:13:35.420052Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
> 2021-07-08T11:43:24.012961Z warning envoy config    StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 0

Comment: It will be really great if someone can take a look and help me understand if there is issue with above configuration.

Comment: Hi @AmolSurve, welcome to Stack Overflow. Correct me if I am wrong, your issue is that everything works with HTTP but not with HTTPS? And you want it to work with HTTPS?

Comment: @PawełGrondal, Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes you are correct everything works with HTTP but not with HTTPS and want it to work with HTTPS.

Comment: Below are the logs from ingress gateway
`2021-07-08T11:13:33.554104Z warning envoy config StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.20.0.51:15012: connect: connection refused"
2021-07-08T11:13:35.420052Z info xdsproxy connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2021-07-08T11:43:24.012961Z warning envoy config StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 0` 
I have also checked that the port is 15012 is open

Comment: I am still facing the issue. Need guidance on the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are facing the issue but if seems like you have enforced mtls . Thats why in the following config for gateway. You might need to open HTTPS also
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
name: sample-gateway
namespace: foo
spec:
selector:
istio: ingressgateway
servers:

- port:
  number: 80
  name: http
  protocol: HTTP
  hosts:

  - "sample.com"
- port:
  number: 443
  name: https
  protocol: HTTPS
  hosts:

  - "sample.com"